# how to update listview item on item click?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have like button in every listitem when i click like button i am calling service to push data to server and finally based on response i want to change like button.i am using below code to change

in activity class

```
CustomSimpleAdapter adapter = new CustomSimpleAdapter (
                    this, arr,
                    R.layout.listviewitem, new String[] {
                            "count", "likes"}, new int[] { 
                            R.id.counttxt, 
                            R.id.likes},list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in custom simpleAdater class

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem, null);
                holder.like = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.like); // title
                holder.count= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.counttxt); // artist
                   vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

              holder.like.setId(position);
        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    int listItemPosition = v.getId();
//calling web service here based on response i want to increase count size

if(respone.equal("success")
{
updatecount(listItemPosition );
}

            }
        });



private void updatecount(int index) {
        View v = list.getChildAt(index - list.getFirstVisiblePosition());
            someText1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.counttxt);//here i am getting null
        int i = Integer.parseInt(data.get(index).get("Count"));
        i++;
        someText1.setText(Integer.toString(i) + "count");
    }
```

when i updating data i am getting null values of listview item.if any one have idea please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i get my solution by update array list after that am calling notifyDataSetChanged()

```
    map.put("like",  increament by previous value);
    arrlist.set(listItemPosition, map);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AdapterView.OnItemClickListener?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

`view` is the list item that was clicked, so if you wanted to alter it, you can just alter the `view` paramter.

Comment: i am using custom adapter class,i am writing onclick in custom adapter class

Comment: you should post your code then. the code posted above doesn't show any of this.

Comment: you shouldn't use onClick for this.. try using an OnItemClickListener and overriding the onItemClick method to do what you want instead of having to call a method to do what you want, just do it in onItemClick.

Comment: how to write onclick for list item in listview onitemclick listener.